# "No such file or directory" error for hashlib++ library in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, libraries, hashlib

I am coding a project in C++ in CodeBlocks, and I am trying to use the hashlib++ library, and I have it in my code as such:

```
#include <hashlibpp.h>
```

When I click "build and run", on that line of code I get the following error:

> fatal error: hashlibpp.h: No such file or directory

I have the entire hashlib++ library in the same directory as my main.cpp file.

I was following the instructions on the documentation at http://hashlib2plus.sourceforge.net/doc/README.TXT.html
but either the instructions in sections 3.1 and 3.2 did not work or I did not follow them properly.

I would appreciate any insight as to why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out what the issue was. By section 3.1,

1. Go to your project in the "Management" tab, and right-click the project you are working on. If you cannot see that section go to View > Manager, or press Shift + F2.
2. After right-clicking, select "add files..." and simply find and add the .h file you will be using. After it should show up in the "Management" section in a folder called "Headers".
3. Type in appropriate `#include` line in your code. I downloaded the entire hashlib2plus folder and put it in my project folder, so mine looked like
   `#include "hashlib2plus/trunk/src/hashlibpp.h"`

Hope this resolves any issues in the future!

Comment: Instead of this, you probably should have added the path to the header files to your include path setting of your project.

Comment: In addition to my response, I also followed the instructions on http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/, and everything works perfectly now, no issues or anything.